# What is the best way to model survival when the hazard rate decreases over time?

Tags: parameter-estimation, survival-analysis, churn

The standard survival analysis model - for example the model which forms the basis for the proportional hazards model - assumes the hazard rate is constant. In many applications this would be the exception rather than the rule.

What parametric model would be appropriate for data such as this:

```
% retention
70%
80%
85%
90%
90%
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Cox model, the *hazard ratio between two levels* is constant - not the hazard rate.

Anyways, most models will be able to model a decreasing hazard rate. The exception being exponential, which *is* constant over time.